# C++ bruteforce program very slow

Tags: c++, performance, popen, brute-force

I got a blackbox program "secret.exe" that accepts a number as an argument. It only accepts one number that I don't know. I want to do a brute force attack to get that number. 
The C++-program below does that but is pretty slow (13 numbers per second). CPU and memory are nearly not consumed by this program. 
What is the bottleneck? Is the popen-function to slow?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
       char psBuffer[128];
       FILE *chkdsk;
       bool nomatch = true;
       int i = 0;
       char cmd[100];
       while(nomatch){
           sprintf (cmd, "secret.exe %d", i++);
           if( (chkdsk = popen( cmd, "rt" )) == NULL )
              cout << "error";
           while( !feof( chkdsk ) ) {
              if( fgets( psBuffer, 128, chkdsk ) != NULL && strcmp(psBuffer, "wrong")){
                  cout << "password: " << --i << endl;
                  cout << "secret info : " << psBuffer << endl;
                  nomatch = false;
              }
           }
           pclose( chkdsk );
       }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Spawning a new process is by many orders more expensive than anything else your program does.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the `popen`, I would have said that this calls for threading, but it may be some system wide resource handling that is blocking so I don't even know if it would make a difference

Comment: Are you practicing your C++ skills with this or you want to get the number ? If you're only interested in number it's easier to decompile secret.exe with [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml).

Comment: Though CPU and memory are not consumed, you may want to watch IO

Comment: I tried. But I can't see the number in there.

Comment: Benchmarking/Profiling made sense. Seems to be the popen- and the pclose-function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to benchmark/profile to find out, but it's entirely possible that `secret.exe` just wastes time.

Comment: I've seen programs do this.  They simply stall for ~1s after an invalid password attempt.  Users are willing to wait that long, but it makes brute force attacks a nightmare.

Comment: No secret.exe doesn't do anything else than checking the argument.

Comment: Benchmarking/Profiling made sense. Seems to be the popen- and the pclose-function.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is *hideously* inefficient at process creation.  You might try [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) on Linux, but I don't know how much of Linux's efficiency will be wasted by pretending to be Windows.  If you're willing to do some digging and ugly hacks, you might be able to load and run the relevant code in your process, but at that point, you're probably better off trying to disassemble/decompile it.